# How to assign data from chrome.storage to Angular component's variable

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

How can I assign data from `chrome.storage.sync.get` to my Angular component's variable?

Here is my component:

```
export class KTableComponent implements OnInit {

  words: string[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loadData() {
    const words = this.words;
    chrome.storage.sync.get({words: []}, function (result) {
      Object.assign(words, result.words)
    });
   // I want to stop here until data retrieved
  }
```

My goal is to retrieve data and after assigning that data to `words` variable, render component again. I know that `chrome.storage.sync.get` works asynchronously and I don't know, how to wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to wait until you get the response back and show the result.

You code should,

- know when the data is loading.
- update when data is loaded

I would rewrite it in thing format.

```
words: string[] = [];
loading = false;

 loadData() {
    const words = this.words;
    loading = true;
    chrome.storage.sync.get({words: []}, this.onDataLoad);

onDataLoad(result) {
      loading = false;
      Object.assign(words, result.words);
    }
```

With this code, you can show a loader while data is being synced, and Angular will update the view for you, when `words` get values assigned.

If you would like to do until there are values for  word object, you can write it in `onDataLoad`.